# MongoDB Replica Set is really slow when a member becomes unavailable

Tags: php, mongodb

we have faced a problem with our production system yesterday which I
am unable to explain when following the official documentation.

**The Setup:**

- MongoDB 2.0.1
- Replica Set spanning over 5 Servers with one preferred Primary
- PHP Application using V 1.2.6 of the PHP Driver
- One collection with roughly 3 million entries
- SlaveOkay set to true for every connection
- The connection string for MongoDB includes all five servers from the replica set

**The Problem:**

Yesterday one of the secondaries suddenly died (hardware crash) and
became totally unavailable. From that point onwards many read
operations carried out from the PHP driver took over 30 seconds to
complete (before it rarely took over 0.1 second).

- rs.status() was clearly reporting that the failed secondary was
  NOK and not accessible.
- all same queries sent directly via the console to the primary or
  any secondary were processed in under 0.1 seconds (as expected)

In the beginning I have taken the reference to the failed secondary
from the connection string in PHP, yet this yielded no change to the
overall performance. Only when I did an explicit
rs.remove(hostname_port) from the replica set did the performance
scale back to normal.

I suppose this is not expected behavior? Can we shield ourselves from
anything like this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a least one [significant bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-260) related to replica sets with the V1.2.6 php driver. Are you able to upgrade the driver to a newer version?

Comment: I will try upgrading now. Hopefully these things are related, as I cannot find any other explanation.

Comment: @clops I do not recommend upgrading to any of the 1.2.7-1.2.10 versions. Some of them sigfault, others have issues when running w/ ReplicaSets under load. I've been experiencing these problems myself and seen other reports as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem yesterday

Scenario: PHP 5.4 + mongodb 2.4.8 replicaset with 3 servers

When the mongodb daemon was down but the same linux server network was up
there was no problem for the php application.

When the linux server of anyone of the three mongodb servers in the replicaset was down the page load was taking forever to finish, **very slow for php**.

My conclusion was that it was not related to mongodb, it was actually a **network issue**.

So I've just set a **timeout** parameter in the options hash of the replicaset connection, like this:

```
$options = [
    "replicaSet"     => $_ENV['MONGODB_REPLICA'], 
    "readPreference" => \MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY_PREFERRED,
    "timeout"        => 1000
];
self::$mongoClient = new \MongoClient($_ENV['MONGODB_URI'], $options);
```

And that solution fixed the problem for me.
I hope it can help you guys too.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem recently.

The solution is to set the mongo "**timeout**" parameter in php.

The reason is different however - when one of the mongodb servers is down the other Linux box is trying to establish a TCP connection to the unreachable mongo instance. The OS will send several SYN packets using predefined intervals  trying to establish the connection. You can see the number of retries by **"cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries** **"**(see more at http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout) . Respectively without the mongo "**timeout**" the php application will have to wait the "OS connection attempt time" which increase the load time significantly.
If the tcp_sync_retreis is too high the PHP might hit the default mongo "timeout" (equaling to PHP default_socket_timeout) before the OS finishes with the connection attempt. PHP will timeout and the web server might return 504 Gateway Timeout error (in our case it was with nginx & php-fpm).

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve this problem?

We are having something similar and it seems to be related to the order of the nodes in the connection string.

If your downed server is first in the connection string, the PHP driver will wait for that connection attempt to time out before trying the second server and so forth. If your timeout is set to the default of 20 seconds, this introduces a huge delay.

We've not got a solution to this, yet.

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? I have figured out the only reliable version to be 1.2.6 ... all others have serious bugs.